# Vuetify use multiple data in :attach v-menu

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuetify.js, attached-properties

I would like to add a class (searchAnchor) in addition to the property (attach). what is the correct spelling here to be able to use a property and a class?

```js
  ....
  attach: {
                type: [String,Boolean],
                default: false
            },.....
```

```html
<template>
    <v-menu absolute
            :z-index="zIndex"
            min-width="100%"
            :attach="attach && 'searchAnchor'"
            transition="slide-y-transition"
            :content-class="contentClasses"
            :nudge-bottom="calcHeight"
            :close-on-content-click="false"
            v-on="$listeners"
            :v-bind="$attrs">.....
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
:attach="attach && 'searchAnchor'"
```

Javascript looks at the variable `attach` and evaluates it. If the evaluation returns true(in your case, it does), it returns the value after the `&&` operator - In your case returning just the `'searchAnchor'` value.

What you want is this

```js
:attach="{ ...attach, searchAnchor: true }"
```

This uses the spread(`...`) operator to copy your object's properties onto a new object and then adds another property to that new object, `searchAnchor` which's value is `true`.